# Outlook OfficeJS API cannot resolve content type if extension is in uppercase

Tags: outlook-web-addins

OfficeJS does not seem to be able to resolve the content type of a file if the file extension is uppercase. This can be easily reproduced by attaching a file with an uppercase file name (e.g. FOO.JPEG) and executing the following code:

```
window.Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments.forEach(function(file) { console.log("name: " + file.name +  " type:" + file.contentType);})
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: Javascript is case-sensitive. OfficeJS uses Javascript.

Comment: The OfficeJS API should still be able to resolve the content type regardless if the file has a extension in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

[`Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox.item#attachments-arrayattachmentdetails) returns Array of [`AttachmentDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_5/office.attachmentdetails?view=office-js). The `AttachmentDetails` represents an attachment on an item from the server and contains properties of the attachment, for example `name`, `size`, etc. One of the property is `contentType`. All of them are just the Exchange properties and whatever Exchange has set into those properties, the JavaScript API will gives you. For example, the following is the attachment with small letters extension ...

[image]

Exchange has completed the `PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG_W` property with content type. If you will use Office Js API `contentType` will return this value. In the same time, the attachment with all CAPS (on our Exchange server) would not have the `PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG_W` at all ...

[image]

This happen because Exchange doesn't have mapping `"JPEG"` extension. Obviously if you would use Office Js API `contentType` function it will return empty string. This is exactly what you observe.

To add this mapping you would need to refer to your System Administrator. As long as the mapping will be added to your environment, Exchange will be resolving this file extensions and Office Js API will deliver this value to you.

Comment: @SameeraJayaseckara The posted screenshots are taken from O365 account. Once again you should contact your IT department to add the extensions you need to lookup, if it possible at all; I am not IT guy and don't know this. As the work around, you may use file extension (`name` property) case insensitive and get the content type in your code handler in case if `contentType` property returns nothing. For example: [mime-types](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-types)